# haproxy: set POST body

Tags: http, post, haproxy

In API gateway that is running on haproxy there is a need to set body of POST request on some urls. I.e. the POST body comes into haproxy as empty and should come out of haproxy as say "some body"

Didn't find the way to manipulate with request body in [haproxy docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html) other than `reqrep`.

Tried to use `reqrep` in the following manner

```
backend body-setter
  reqrep ^$ \1some\ body
```

but it does not set the body.

Even tried something like

```
backend body-replacer
  reqrep ^a$ some\ body
```

and send the "a" POST body to it, hoping that body will be replaced, but it just does not change.

Is there no way at all to manipulate POST body with haproxy?